# How do I pass the props from this child component to the parent form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wescoff-9yxxh?file=/src/App.js)

Let's say you select community dialogue in the form and click Next, you will see the error `Cannot read property 'm15_19_reached' of undefined` in the next step

The `PeopleReached` component is a child of the App component and it has some input textbox. I am trying to pass props of the value selected from the component textboxes input to the App. But it seems I am missing something in the questions.js where I set the value.

Comment: what is `m15_19_reached` ? and what object should it be attached to?

Comment: @red-baron ```m15_19_reached``` is one of six textbox input fields in the PeopleReached child component. The user is expected to fill all the 6 fields and the values will be sent as part of the ```setFormData```

Comment: well the object is undefined that `m15_19_reached` is part of. can you log out that object and confirm that? you may need to add some checks to ensure you only render it once the object is define

Answer (score 0):

Add a null check for `props.question.value` inside the value property for all the 6 `TextFields`.

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  name="m15_19_reached"
  type="number"
  value={(props.question.value && props.question.value.m15_19_reached) || ""}
  onChange={handleTextInput1}
  error={props.error && !!props.error.i}
  helperText={props.error ? props.error.i : ""}
  label={"Age 15-19 year"}
  className="form-control"
/>
```

Comment: Tnanks @neel-dsouza I will check it out